# unable to trigger select event on jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

i have a search form whith jquery autocomplete on some fields.

```
<form id="prjs_form" class="prjcts" action="<wp:action path="/ExtStr2/do/enpim/projects/list.action" />" method="post">

    <div class="row bord">
        <div class="wid_ut">
            <span class="label"><wp:i18n key="ACRONYM" /></span> 
            <span class="field"><input id="autAcronym" type="text" name="bean.acronym" value="${bean.acronym}" class="lrg autocomplete" /></span>
        </div>

        ......................

    <div class="row">
        <div class="act_btns">
            <input type="submit" name="search" value="<wp:i18n key='SEARCH'/>">
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

My need is to submit the form when I select one of the values ​​suggested by autocomplete.
this is my jquery

```
jQuery('#autAcronym').autocomplete({
    params: { type: 'project_acronym' },
    paramName: 'text',
                serviceUrl: '<wp:info key="systemParam" paramName="applicationBaseURL" />json/hall.ShowParameters',
                minChars: 2,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    if(ui.item){
                        $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
                    }
                    $('#prjs_form').submit();
                    return false;
                }
});
```

when i start typing on field the autocomplete work fine, but when i select one of the suggested value the select event doesn't trigger....

what's wrong?

the other similar post on stackoverflow doesn't solved my problem

thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps add a console.log as your first line in the select handler. Maybe it is running, and your other code in the event is wrong.

Comment: i found the problem... it was not the original jquery autocomplete but a modified one :-(.... i changed the import in my page... and changed my code